# Set-up MSUnit tests using inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to set-up a test initialise function that handles some basic database set-up tasks; here's my base class:

```
[ TestClass]
public class BaseTest
{
    private SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    protected SqlTransaction sqlTransaction;

    [TestInitialize ()]
    protected void InitialiseConnection()
    {  
        // Set-up sqlTransaction

    }

    [ TestCleanup ()]
    protected void RollbackConnection()
    {
        // Cleanup
    }
```

Then I'm using it like this:

```
[ TestClass]
public class MyTest : BaseTest
{

    [ TestMethod ]
    public void MyFirstTest()
    {
         /// Access DB here crashes because sqltransaction is null
```

A breakpoint on the base class reveals that it isn't calling the `InitialiseConnection` method.  Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm not positive, but have you tried making `InitialiseConnection` and `RollbackConnection` `public` instead of `protected`? Just a shot in the dark really (the examples I've seen and used had them public). EDIT: Also, if your break point isn't being hit, are the methods actually empty and are you running in release mode?

Comment: Yup.. it should be public .. you can have a virtual method though which you would like to use when some additional initialization is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the method marked with `TestInitialize` public instead of protected. I remember having similar problems when the signature didn't exactly match the one in the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx).

Comment: This is correct - the methods need to be public and it will work.